# Can a C++ DLL (not CLI) invoke .NET Core 3.0 delegate?

Tags: c++, .net-core, delegates

I can invoke a C++ DLL function by using dllimport.

But I wish to pass a delegate to C++ so that I can callback after the task is completed.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a `Delegate` to a function pointer using [`Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getfunctionpointerfordelegate?view=netframework-4.8) and then pass the function pointer to C++.